# what issue tracking software does linux development use?

Tags: linux, git, issue-tracking

The reason I ask this is because it seems silly to me to contrive an issue tracking system for git when linux development must already have one that works perfectly for git. In fact, git is *designed* around linux development (from everything I understand), and so as far as I can tell, git must implicitly already have/work-with an issue-tracking system.

Perhaps linux development doesn't use issue tracking *software*, but surely the developers have some *system*.

What issue tracking system does linux development use?

Comment: What issue tracking does git use ? -1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/)?

Also, [see this](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/InterfacesFrontendsAndToolsWishlist).

Comment: Oh. That's unexpected by me that a non-git issue-tracking system would be used for linux development. I see why people have made their own. Thanks.

Comment: No problems! If the unexpected answer is what you expected [sic], you can accept it. :-)